# Creating a Cocoa app using C or Perl (NOT Objective-C)

Tags: c, cocoa, perl, macos

I'm having a hard time understanding how to use Cocoa with either C or Perl.

Background:
I've seen it mentioned in quite a few places that Mac's Cocoa API can be used with C, Perl etc. but I haven't found any information on how to go about doing this. I've also found a couple of articles saying that Cocoa can be used with Objective-C only.

I've seen CamelBones for Perl but it looks like I have to use XCode and a fair amount of Objective-C to use it.

Are there any resources on building a Cocoa app using just a C compiler and a text editor?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you don't want to learn Objective-C, then forget about writing Cocoa apps.  The Python and Ruby bridges are for using existing libraries in a Cocoa app, they are not a way for you to live in a bubble and avoid learning a new language.

Comment: I agree, you will always have to jump through hoops to get stuff done with the pyobjc to work with the cocoa api anyway. Might as well learn it, the doco is good, rather than bastardise a language to kinda fit.

Comment: Another +1.  There is no guarantee that any Cocoa-to-language-x bridge is going to stick around, and none of them work as well as Objective-C.  The very concepts of Cocoa are designed around it, so chances are if you can't eventually figure out some decent Obj-C, any "Cocoa" you write will be bad Cocoa.

Comment: With Camelbones, you do not actually have to write any Objective-C code. However, you have to use the Cocoa (and other native) frameworks, but I suppose this is exactly the point (when writing Mac applications).